# Dictionary group by value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have a `TimeEntry class` and a `Dictionary` with the `Id` as Key and the other Properties as Value. Now i want to group the dictionary by the value of `Category`

```
 class TimeEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format($"Start Time: {StartTime}, EndTime: {EndTime}, Task: {Task}, Category {Category}");
        }
    }
```

```
private readonly IDictionary<int, TimeEntry> _timeEntries;
```

I want to display something like this:

```
Household 
   00:30:00 do something
   00:30:00 do some stuff
work 
   01:30:00 go to work 
   00:30:00 to some work thing
```

it has to be grouped by category

Comment: every value has a different key

Comment: Taking the `Values` and using LINQ’s `GroupBy` probably would be an easy way. Then converting the output to whatever format you want, like a dictionary of lists

Comment: i alreasy tried to do it with LINQ but i'm not very good at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `GroupBy` in *Linq*, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

_timeEntries                       // from given dictionary we want
  .Values                          //   Values
  .GroupBy(item => item.Category)  //   Grouped By Category
```

For instance:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, _timeEntries
  .Values
  .GroupBy(item => item.Category)
//.OrderBy(group => group.Key, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
  .Select(group => 
     $"{group.Key}\r\n  {string.Join("\r\n  ", group.Select(item => $"{item.StartTime} {item.Task}"))}"));
```

The only difficulty is to *represent* `group` within final `Select`

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Another question for you, how can i sum all the start time in one catagory?

Comment: @nurix: Well, I doubt if you can **sum** `StartTime` at all. How can you sum, say, `12 Dec 2019 15:55:50` and `5 Oct 2010 23:50:50`?  in any case, I suggest having `StartTime`, `EndTime` not as `string`, but as `DateTime`, `TimeSpan` etc.

Comment: Well i've a method insteat of StartTime who returns a TimeSpan, so it should be possible, shouldn't it?

Comment: @nurix: yes, `TimeSpan` (i.e. *duration*) can easily be summed (say, `01:12:05 + 03:58:40 == 05:10:45`)

Comment: but how can i do it with linq

Comment: Something like this: we can't `Sum` `TimeSpan` excplicly, but we can sum secondsL `TimeSpan result = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(items.Sum(item => item.f StartTime(/*your method */) .TotalSeconds));`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
_timeEntries.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Category).ThenBy(x => x.Value.StartTime)
```

Category -> StartTime.

You can add as many as you need to:

```
_timeEntries.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Category).ThenBy(x => x.Value.StartTime).ThenBy(x => x.Value.EndTime).ThenByDescending(x => x.Value.Task)
```

Category -> StartTime -> EndTime -> (Descending) Task
etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to do some calculations with date (start and end), you will need to change it to DateTime:

```
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Then if you prefer more imperative way:

```
foreach (var group in _timeEntries.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Category))
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (var entry in group)
    {
        var timespan = entry.Value.EndTime - entry.Value.StartTime;
        Console.WriteLine($"  {timespan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")} {entry.Value.Task}");
    }
}
```